# Custom font work in the editor but dont show up on the software

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

I have a custom font that I add on my project and I make it work.
This is how it look like in the editor with the WPF code :

```
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ArabicFont1}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Run Text="{Binding text_arabe}"/>
    </TextBlock>
```

[Font displayed on the editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhbcu.png)

But when I start the app, this is what font I have, with the exact same text :

[Font when the app is started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiDAc.png)

So as you can see it's two different font, but in the editor, it show the right one and in the software the default one

So I don't really understand, can someone help me with this, please?

Thank you

If it can help- here is the app.xml

```
    <Application.Resources>
    
    <Style x:Key="ArabicFont1">
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily"
        Value="pack://application:,,,/fonts/#noorehidayat" />
    </Style>
    
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: You probably want to tag your question `wpf`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the font is installed on the executing system or the font is found in the execution folder of your application.

Please look at this example, maybe this will help you:
[Use custom fonts in wpf c# applications](https://parallelcodes.com/use-custom-fonts-in-wpf-c-applications/)

Comment: still not working sorry

Comment: Please provide us, how you embedd the resource in your application by sharing the window ressources code, than we can provide you a better solution.

Comment: You mean the App.xaml where I put the font ? I edited my post for that

Comment: I´ve edited my solution with a working example tutorial. Please test it this way.

Comment: I'm sorry it dont work